# Creating custom graphs for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am trying to develop a grapher app for Windows Phone, and I am referring to the app in the link below to create graphs of mathematical functions:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/grapher-calculator/fd1e8989-f094-4b3d-ba87-d76758b8a023

Can anyone please let me know how graphs are created in this app? Does the Windows Phone 8 toolkit support realtime graphing of cartesian and polar equations?  If so, how? How are the graphs being created in the app given in the above URL?

Comment: When you say 'Does **our** toolkit support...', do you mean the Windows Phone 8 toolkit?

Comment: yes .. in windows phone 8 is there any support to draw graphs like this??

Comment: I don't know the answer myself, but I have edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below links, these may help you

[Red control chart for windows phone](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radchart-series-chartseries.html)

[red control for windows phone](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx)

[Step by step working with telrik for windows phone](http://telerikhelper.net/2013/03/06/step-by-step-working-with-telerik-charts-in-windows-phone-8/)

I have created this type of charts using telrik and it works gr8 for me.

Hope it will help you too.